# Как уменьшить значения по экспоненте?

Tags: java, android

Есть массив

```
int[] a1 = new int[50000];
```

Надо пересчитать значения массива, чтобы они уменьшались по экспоненте.

Изначально значения массива это числа равные 20000. 
После пересчета они должны уменьшаться и прийти к нулю.
Как это сделать используя возможности java?

Comment: а пример можно? Что-то вообще не понятно что вы хотите получить.

Comment: Результат: массив в котором значения убывают по ЭКСПОНЕНТЕ. Т.е. каждое значение массива нужно на что-то умножить, а на что я не понимаю. Где применяется: затухание сигналов например.

Comment: вы хотите умножить каждое число массива на какое-то число меньше 1? А в чём проблема тогда?..

Comment: проблема в том, что число на которое я буду умножать должно быть таким, чтобы результат уменьшался по экспоненте. Такое впечатление что понятие экспоненты уже никто не помнит, в этом и проблема. Другими словами, как посчитать этот коэффициент, на который надо умножать значения.

Comment: Я просто намекну. Экспонента - число 2.718281828459045 и так далее. И да, если вам надо подобрать **число** то вопрос не имеет отношения к этому.

Comment: `Math.exp(double a)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Пример:**  i^e*20000

```
    double[] ints = new double[50000];
    Arrays.fill(ints, 20000d);

    for (int i = ints.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) ints[i] = Math.pow(i, Math.E) * ints[i];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Именно это мне и было нужно! Спасибо огромное!